# can not get $_POST values in php on ajax request

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

Here is my **index.html**

```
<script>
    var xml = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xml.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if (xml.readyState === 4 && xml.status === 200) {
            console.log(xml.responseText);
        }
    }
    xml.open("POST", "ajax.php", true);
    var data = new FormData();
    data.append("name","Sahan");
    xml.send(data);
</script>
```

And here is my **ajax.php**

```
<?php
echo "Hello " . $_POST["name"];
?>
```

When I run this on my localhost result is

> **Notice**:  Undefined index: name in **C:\xampp\htdocs\chat\ajax.php** on line **2**
>       Hello

But when I am using **JQuery** It is Working Correctly...

And my question is how I send ajax using JavaScript without JQuery..?

Comment: Have a look at the developer tools to see whether the POST array really contains the values you expect

Comment: There is no value in $_POST array

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to pass proper header information along with request when you use ajax with post data

```
<script>
    var xml = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xml.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if (xml.readyState === 4 && xml.status === 200) {
            console.log(xml.responseText);
        }
    }
    xml.open("POST", "ajax.php", true);
    //Send the proper header information along with the request
    xml.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    /*var data = new FormData();
    data.append("name","Stackoverflow");*/
    xml.send("name=Stackoverflow");
</script>
```

Comment: yes.........it is works.......but i chaged send to xml.send("name=Data"); like that after changed it worked thank you...

Comment: The online examples [e.g. here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects) don't seem to mention this at all. Any idea why this is necessary?

Comment: what is the request header for GET ..?

Comment: You dont need to pass request header for get, Simply add query string along with url: `xml.open("GET", "ajax.php?name=xyz", true);`

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code in your javascript function.

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
  };
xhttp.open("POST", "ajax_test.php", true);
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhttp.send("fname=Stack&lname=Overflow");
```

for more details [Ajax at w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp)